# symfony choice type should accept array of models

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I cannot find the correct way to pass an array of 'models' to the choice type. It expects the 'norm' data, but that might be code duplication is many cases imho.

**Duplicates code of model transformer**

```
    $vehicles = $repo->findAll();

    $vehicleChoice = $builder
        ->create('vehicle', 'choice', [
            'choices' => \array_map(
                function(Vehicle $v) {
                    return $v->getId(); // same as VehicleModelTransformer::transform
                }, $vehicles),
        ])
        ->addModelTransformer(
            new VehicleModelTransformer($this->em)
        )
    ;
```

vs.

**Form should use model transformer to initialize with norm data**

```
   $vehicleChoice = $builder
        ->create('vehicle', 'choice', [
            'choices_as_model' => $repo->findAll(), // anything like that
        ])
        ->addModelTransformer(
            new VehicleModelTransformer($this->em)
        )
    ;
```

Anyone knows how to write it the second way, or to convert the array of models to norm data? In the symfony components `modelToNorm` is a private method. That code is also not reusable.

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question... I found it looking for the opposite - for a way to feed an array of ViewData to an EntityType field, instead feeding it with a QueryBuilder. And to have the EntityType auto convert the needed array of view data to model where needed (on form submits etc).

Answer (score 0):

As I see you already has own dataTransformer which make
everything for your purpose.
So I think that the better solution for this case is create custom
form type like VehicleChoice which will extend built-in choice type 
and will contain required logic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11574540)

Comment: I recommended to create custom from type as solution and put logic inside it. So I'm a bit confused concern your comment

Comment: Your answer as flagged as "too short" do be a real answer and not a simple comment. I suggest you to add more details to let users understand "why" your solution could be a good one or maybe the best one. You're suggesting a different approach but you're not giving user further details to how achieve it